# Represent a video as a 2D Array where each column represents a frame - OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv

My goal is to transform a video into a 2D matrix **X**, where the column vectors represent a frame. So the matrix has the dimension: **X**.shape ---> (# features of a frame, # total number of frames)

I need this form because I want to apply different ML algorithms on **X**.  To get **X** I proceed as follows:

1. upload the video in python with the OpenCV library and save all frames.
2. Loop{

```
a) Frame (=3D array with dimensions height, width, depth=3 rbg) is converted into a 1D vector x 

b) Append vector x to Matrix X

}
```

For step 2 b) I use

```
video_matrix = np.column_stack((video_matrix, frame_vector))
```

This operation takes about 0.5s for a 640x320 frame.  For a small video with 3min (8000 frames) the calculation of X takes almost 150 minutes.  Is there a way to make it faster?

Code for the first part:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('path/video.mp4') 
if not os.path.exists('data'): 
    os.makedirs('data') 

counter = 0 
while(True):   
    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = video.read() 
  
    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = './data/frame' + str(counter) + '.jpg'
        #print ('Creating...' + name) 
        
        # writing the extracted images 
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame) 
  
        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        counter += 1
    else: 
        break
   
# Release all space and windows once done 
video.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the second part which is to slow

```
video_matrix = np.zeros(width * height * 3) # initialize 1D array which will become the 2D array; first column will be deleted at the end

for i in range(counter): # loops over the total amount of frames
    
    current_frame = np.asarray(Image.open('./data/frame'+str(i)+'.jpg')) # 3D-array = current frame
    frame_vector = image_to_vector(current_frame) #convert frame into a 1D array
    video_matrix = np.column_stack((video_matrix, frame_vector)) # append frame x to a matrix X that will represent the video
    
video_matrix = np.delete(video_matrix, 0, 1) # delete the initialized zero column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not repeatedly append single frames to your accumulated data. that'll cost you O(n^2), i.e. the program will run ever slower the more it has to read. numpy can't enlarge arrays in-place. it has to create a copy every time. the copying effort increases with every additional frame.

append each frame to a python list. when you're done reading the video, convert the whole list into a numpy array once.

Answer (score -1):

Here's is the Python (Keras) code for 'Video Data' generation & preprocessing before passing through a DL based classification model:

```
import numpy as np
# preparing dataset
X_train = []
Y_train = []
labels = enumerate([‘left’, ‘right’, ‘up’, ‘down’]) #4 classes
num_vids = 30
num_imgs = 30
img_size = 20
min_object_size = 1
max_object_size = 5
# video frames with left moving object
for i_vid in range(num_vids):
 imgs = np.zeros((num_imgs, img_size, img_size)) # set background to 0
 #vid_name = ‘vid’ + str(i_vid) + ‘.mp4’
 w, h = np.random.randint(min_object_size, max_object_size, size=2)
 x = np.random.randint(0, img_size — w)
 y = np.random.randint(0, img_size — h)
 i_img = 0
 while x>0:
 imgs[i_img, y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255 # set rectangle as foreground
 x = x-1
 i_img = i_img+1
 X_train.append(imgs)
for i in range(0,num_imgs):
 Y_train.append(0)
# video frames with right moving object
for i_vid in range(num_vids):
 imgs = np.zeros((num_imgs, img_size, img_size)) # set background to 0
 #vid_name = ‘vid’ + str(i_vid) + ‘.mp4’
 w, h = np.random.randint(min_object_size, max_object_size, size=2)
 x = np.random.randint(0, img_size — w)
 y = np.random.randint(0, img_size — h)
 i_img = 0
 while x<img_size:
 imgs[i_img, y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255 # set rectangle as foreground
 x = x+1
 i_img = i_img+1
 X_train.append(imgs)
for i in range(0,num_imgs):
 Y_train.append(1)
# video frames with up moving object
for i_vid in range(num_vids):
 imgs = np.zeros((num_imgs, img_size, img_size)) # set background to 0
 #vid_name = ‘vid’ + str(i_vid) + ‘.mp4’
 w, h = np.random.randint(min_object_size, max_object_size, size=2)
 x = np.random.randint(0, img_size — w)
 y = np.random.randint(0, img_size — h)
 i_img = 0
 while y>0:
 imgs[i_img, y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255 # set rectangle as foreground
 y = y-1
 i_img = i_img+1
 X_train.append(imgs)
for i in range(0,num_imgs):
 Y_train.append(2)
# video frames with down moving object
for i_vid in range(num_vids):
 imgs = np.zeros((num_imgs, img_size, img_size)) # set background to 0
 #vid_name = ‘vid’ + str(i_vid) + ‘.mp4’
 w, h = np.random.randint(min_object_size, max_object_size, size=2)
 x = np.random.randint(0, img_size — w)
 y = np.random.randint(0, img_size — h)
 i_img = 0
 while y<img_size:
 imgs[i_img, y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255 # set rectangle as foreground
 y = y+1
 i_img = i_img+1
 X_train.append(imgs)
for i in range(0,num_imgs):
 Y_train.append(3)

# data pre-processing
from keras.utils import np_utils
X_train=np.array(X_train, dtype=np.float32) /255
X_train=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_imgs, img_size, img_size, 1)
print(X_train.shape)
Y_train=np.array(Y_train, dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1)
print(Y_train.shape)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 4)
```

It should help you.

Comment: Yes. Syntaxes (paragraphs, indentations etc.) may be wrong. Actually i copied it from my blog. Please correct as per your need.